# jQuery event binding does not work properly or i can't make it properly working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events, bind

**HTML:**

```
<input id="email" name="email" type=text />
<input id="password name="password" type="password" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var fields = ["email","password"];
for (var i in fields) {
    var field = $("#"+fields[i]);
    field.bind({
        focus: function() {
            field.css("border-color","#f00");
        },
        blur: function() {
            field.css("border-color","#000");
        }
    });
}
```

My **desire action** will be as follows:

1. When I place cursor on any of the above fields the input field's border will be red.
2. When I take away the cursor from the field it's border will be black.

But the event is **occurs only for the password filed** whether I place and take away cursor form **any of the above fields**.

Comment: you have not closed your id="password"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a *really common problem*, the `field` variable accessed on the `focus` and `blur` event belongs to the outer scope, so it contains *the last* iterated value, in your case it will contain `"password"`.

There are a lot of ways to solve this, for example you could use `$.each` which introduces a new scope:

```
jQuery.each(["email", "password"], function(index, fieldId) {
  var field = $('#'+fieldId);

  field.bind({
    focus: function() {
      field.css("border-color","#f00");
    },
    blur: function() {
      field.css("border-color","#000");
    }
  });
});
```

Or using `$(this)` instead of `field` in your event handlers, i.e.:

```
var fields = ["email","password"];
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    $("#"+fields[i]).bind({
        focus: function() {
            $(this).css("border-color","#f00");
        },
        blur: function() {
            $(this).css("border-color","#000");
        }
    });
}
```

<sub>Off-topic note: also in the above example that I use a normal loop, instead the `for...in` statement, which is not really meant to be used on array-like objects.</sub>

Try out the two code examples [here](http://jsbin.com/eqisi3/edit).

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$('input#email, input#password').bind({
    focus: function() {
        $(this).css("border-color","#f00"); 
    },
    blur: function() {
        $(this).css("border-color","#000"); 
    }
});
```

You may also need to clean up your HTML if the typos in your question are in the real thing:

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" />
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
```

Comment: this is definitely the best solution, unless there are more fields in the array or the fields are dynamic

Comment: whoops, looks like you beat me to the punch :)

Answer (score 0):

One additional note that could improve your code.  jQuery does almost everything by iterating over sets, so there is no need to manually iterate over a list of keys with a for loop.  Instead, you can just do this:

```
$("#email, #password").bind({ // grab both elements at once
    focus: function() {
        $(this).css("border-color","#f00");
    },
    blur: function() {
        $(this).css("border-color","#000");
    }
});
```

Note that, as in CMS's example, I am using `this` to reference the element within the handler functions.  `this` will refer to the node on which the event was triggered, so it will be `#email` when focusing in that field, and `#password` when focusing on the other.o