# Click event is launching only once

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a form in which I have many checkboxes.  I need to post the data to the controller upon any checkbox checked or unchecked, i.e a click on a checbox must post to the controller, and there is no submit button.  What will be the bet method in this case?  I have though of Ajax.BeginForm and have the codes below.  The problem i`m having is that the checkbox click event is being detected only once and after that the click event isn`t being launched.  Why is that  so?  How can I correct that?

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tests"}))
         {%>
               <div id="tests">
                    <%Html.RenderPartial("Details", Model); %>
               </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" style="Visibility:hidden" id="btnSubmit"/> 
          <%}
          %>

 $(function() {
 $('input:checkbox').click(function() {
        $('#btnSubmit').click();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Wait, which click event?  The one on the form or the one on the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#myForm').submit()`.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this post out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879776/jquery-event-binding-does-not-work-properly-or-i-cant-make-it-properly-working).  I think you need to use the each keyword and bind so that binding is done everytime.

Answer (score 0):

As a debugging step, try doing something else during the click event, like

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    $('#debugDiv').append('click event fired at ' + new Date().toString());
});
```

to see if the issue has something to do with the form submission.

Something else you can try is using jQuery's live function instead of click: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Simply the live keywoed has solved the problem.  Thank you.
$("input:checkbox").live('click', function(){
            $('#myForm').click();
        });
      });